# Texture Baking, Texture is randomised

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking

When I try to bake my Texture the result looks like blender randomised the Grid of the texture.
Could it be that I somehow changed an option or something like that?
Here is the baked map which should only have a Rock material on it.[image]

I baked it with the Diffuse Bake Type and without Direct and Indirect Influence.(I use Cycles)
I tried adding seams to the Uv map but that didn't change anything at the porblem.
Here is another image.
[image: Image of the problem]

As you can see here the selected faces should all be a rock material but on the Texture I baked they are mixed with my other materials.
I tried to make a new model and that didn't changed it.
I'm not very experienced with blender so I hope somebody could help me with my problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have modifiers?

Comment: No I don't have modifiers on the object.